# What privileges do I have (find out within bourne shell script)

Tags: shell-script, permissions, home, bourne-shell

I am hacking away on a remote helper for git. The script is in bourne shell.

I wanted to create some temporary directory in the home dir. For some reason I get permission denied. From my shell directly I can run the same command without problems.

All the Environment vars look normal, $HOME, $USER, ... The homedir has normal permissions set (eg. everything is owned an writable by the user). I'm using debian testing.

This is the offending command:

```
mkdir --mode=600 --parents /home/<user>/.tmp/$$
```

The peculiar thing is also that the directory is effectively created, but the next line that tries to put a file in it has a permission denied again and this time the file is not created.

The shell is running with:

```
set -e # errexit
set -u # nounset
set -f # noglob
set -C # noclobber

set -x
```

but without them I still get permission denied.

ps: I just tried in the $GIT_DIR, to which the user has write privileges too, and also permission denied, but this time  not on the directory creation, but on the file creation the next line.

**So how do I find out who is denying me and why?**

Comment: What user is the script being ran as?

Comment: @JoelDavis not quite sure what you mean, a normal user, uid 1000+...

Comment: You are using mode 0600 (u=rw) which lacks the execute bit which is required for a directory in order to create files inside it.

Comment: @jw013 Thanks alot, that's it. However then I got "cannot create !: File exists" which was blatantly untrue. I was creating it by redirecting to it with `>!` because of the noclobber, but when making that just `>` it works.

Comment: @nus The redirection operator in sh is `>|`, not `>!`. `>!` is the csh equivalent (zsh has both).